# Being a non-native English writer how can i improve my English Writing style?

Tags: fiction, style, novel, planning, process

I'm an Indian and trying to write a novel based on 2 sisters.
My problem is that i don't feel very comfortable with my english sometimes. How can i improve my english?
And sometimes i use the same words a lots of times which is not good i guess, for example the use of word **English** in this question itself. What alternatives can i use?
By the way i read a lots of english novels, watch movies and listen english songs as it is considered a good solution. I'm fluent in my english but just sometimes i feel i lack writing style a bit.
What can i do?
PS:-I'm just 20 so i guess i can't really be very mature but still i aspire to become a writer and that's all i want.

Comment: Hi Anvita! Welcome to Writers.SE, and best of luck with your writing! Part of how this site works is, we try to merge between different people asking the same thing - that means we don't answer the same questions over and over, and you've got a page all ready with responses. I'm going to mark this one as a duplicate; I hope the existing answers help!

Comment: Other related pages: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/how-to-master-literary-american-english-as-a-second-language , http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10379/struggling-to-writing-in-english .

Comment: Hi! i'm new to this community. had no idea how things workor if the question has already been asked.
by the way thanks for the links.

Comment: That's absolutely fine :) Telling newcomers how the site works is a lot of what we do :) Welcome to the site, and happy writing!

Answer (score 0):

Read and write in English as much as you can.  Use English exclusively in your life, if at all possible.

One of the greatest writers in the English language, Joseph Conrad (author of Heart of Darkness), was in his twenties when he learned English, and it was his fourth language.

Coming from another culture, you have an opportunity to bring an uncommon perspective to English language literature.  Good luck!

Comment: "Joseph Conrad"?  sure be the exception, Just need to be born in an intellectual environment, learn some English as a child as well as other European languages that are roots to English, become a British citizen, master the intricacies of the English language and literature during the next 16 years, then write a novel whose potential publisher judges as "uncertain whether the English was good enough for publication."